# How to pass a variable to the SOQL where clause?

Tags: api, salesforce-id, c#

I am using Salesforce API with C#. In the query that I am writing I am not sure how to pass a parameter to the select statement. My query works when it looks like this:

```
SOQL = "select AuthorId,Name, Description,Type from Document where AuthorId='005G0000003s4a8IAA'";
```

But I am not sure how to replace the value in `AuthorId` that is `'005G0000003s4a8IAA'` to a variable that I am passing to this method, like:

```
SOQL = "select AuthorId,Name, Description,Type from Document where AuthorId=" + id;
```

But this is not working. What is the correct format to pass the `id` variable as a query argument?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you are just building a string, you need to wrap the Id in single quotes.

```
SOQL = "select AuthorId,Name, Description,Type from Document where AuthorId='" + id + "'";
```

As was suggested in a comment, you should also escape any potentially harmful strings found in Id. I'm not familiar with the C# functions, but there should be some sort of URLEscape method.

Comment: Since this is not using Apex's parameter binding, the string should probably be sanitized in your C# code. At the very least, escape `'` characters: `\'`.

Answer (score 0):

if the id is not an integer, please read about sql injection and parameter binding and/or sanitizing like suggested by John Gaughan.